# Qual é a diferença entre repeat e while no lua?

Tags: lua

Existe alguma diferença quanto a usabilidade do `repeat` e `while` no Lua?

Na minha opnião, os dois aparentam ter a mesma finalidade.

Não levando em consideração a sintaxe, existe alguma diferença entre eles, ainda que seja mínima?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basicamente o `repeat` equivale ao `do ... while` de outras linguagens.

No [`while`](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.3.html), você está dando a condição para entrar no *loop*. Se a condição for falsa, as operações realizadas dentro da estrutura não serão executadas nenhuma vez.

```
local i = 1
while a[i] do
  print(a[i])
  i = i + 1
end
```

No [`repeat`](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.2.html), você dá a condição na saída, usando `until`. Ao menos uma vez, serão executadas as instruções dentro do *loop*.

```
repeat
  line = os.read()
until line ~= ""
print(line)
```

Interessante observar esta diferença conceitual:

- no [`while`](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.3.html), a condição **verdadeira** faz com que você **permaneça** dentro do *loop*.
- No [`until`](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.2.html) a condição **verdadeira** faz com que você **saia** de dentro do *loop*.

<sup><sub>A tradução para o português de **"while"** é **"enquanto"**, e a de **"repeat ... until"** é **"repita ... até que"**.</sub></sup>

Comment: É verdade. Interessante. Apesar de `do` ser uma palavra chave, ela não é complemento do `while` como no caso do php

Answer (score 0):

Pense como se while fosse "enquanto" e repeat until fosse "repita até que".
Por exemplo

```
repeat
wait()
num=num+1
until var==true
```

Esse loop irá repitir até que `var==true`

já

```
while var==true do
wait()
num=num+1
end
```

irá executar o loop enquanto `var==true`,e irá fazer isso até que você pare o jogo,diferente do `repeat`,que é executado apenas uma vez.
Espero que isso tenha ajudado ;)