# Como transformar um estrutura while em for? E vice-versa?

Tags: algoritmo, while, for, loop

estou precisando de uma explicação sobre como transformar uma estrutura em while para for e vice-versa. Desde já agradeço quem puder ajudar!

Comment: Como assim? Se você entender bem como as duas funcionam, vai saber como adaptar qualquer problema nas duas soluções

Comment: Explique melhor o motivo. Você quer saber simplesmente como fazer um for funcionar como um while, e um while funcionar como um for, ou você quer saber como reestruturar uma repetição para a estrutura mais correta?

Comment: Tem alguma linguagem específica?

Comment: Por favor especifique uma linguagem (cada linguagem tem meios diferentes de fazer um `for`, `while` já é mais padronizado mas ainda assim pode haver discrepâncias), e também mostre o que você já sabe sobre essas estruturas e o que ainda falta saber. Dê um exemplo de código, se possível. Da forma como está, é difícil saber o que está perguntando, mas esses ajustes podem deixar a pergunta mais focada (e "respondível").

Answer (score 5):

Como não definiu a linguagem na pergunta, segue um exemplo "genérico" que itera de 1 a 10:

```
for( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {

   ... conteudo ...

}
```

Equivalente com `while`:

```
i = 1;
while( i <= 10 ) {

   ... conteudo ...

   i++;
}
```

Basicamente, o `for` é composto por 3 partes em sua definição:

```
for( inicializacao; teste para determinar se executa; operação ao final de cada iteração )
```

O `while` é uma versão "enxuta" do for:

```
while(  teste para determinar se executa )
```

Portanto, as outras duas situações que o `for` tem a mais devem ser feitas antes do `while` e dentro do seu bloco de execução.

Agora, o que pode complicar, é quando você tem interrupções/alterações de fluxo, com `continue`, `break` e equivalentes. Veja um pouco mais sobre isso nesta resposta:

> [Deve-se usar break em for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88747/)

Outras considerações:

Temos ainda o `do ... while`, que pode ser visto aqui:

> [Qual é a utilidade e importância de "do... while"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78493/70)

E em Lua temos também o `repeat`:

> [Qual é a diferença entre repeat e while no lua?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104691/70)

Comment: Seria bom colocar um corpo no loop, para deixar claro (no exemplo, no texto já está bom) que o `i++` tem que ser a última coisa no `while`.

Comment: eventualmente que `while(cond){A}` = `for( ; cond ; ){A}`

Comment: @mgibsonbr vou melhorar em vários aspectos. Até entendo o i++ pode ser em qualquer lugar do while desde que não usado no loop, mas entendi o que você disse. E tem outras melhorias necessárias, quero ver se trato de break, continue etc, e o que você mencionou no seu comment eu esclareço melhor na próxima edição.